# Drools Error while deploying into KIE-server : Fire rule limit reached 10000

Tags: json, drools, kie

I am getting this below error in Drools while invoking via JSON. But the same jar and request works fine after restart of the server. Not sure of what is the exact reason for this occurrence.

**Error JSON Response :**

```
{
   "type": "FAILURE",
   "msg": "Error calling container MotorPolicyRules_1.0.1: [PrePolicy.TW_OD:1 -- [TW_OD_Computation:3 - Get Max Discount:8] -- Fire rule limit reached 10000, limit can be set via system property org.jbpm.rule.task.firelimit or via data input of business rule task named FireRuleLimit",
   "result": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a [limit](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.7.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_business_rule_task_fire_limit) whose purpose is to protect your application from looping rules. *Unless* you have a very rare situation where you legitimately need to trigger the same rule 10,000 times (or 10,000 rules altogether), then you likely have an issue with how your rules are designed and should investigate. This exception is being thrown to alert you to this potentially dangerous situation.

(A legitimate use case for exceeding 10,000 rules would be a set of rule which need to act on multiple rows in a large spreadsheet.)

Why you're hitting this limit could be a number of things, from how the rules and inputs are designed to how you're managing your sessions. You'll need to debug into your server the next time you run into this situation (*prior to restarting*, clearly) and take a look around at what is going on and how you're passing information into the rule engine.

Comment: Agreed Roddy. It looks like there is a code leakage in my rules that makes Drools to run an infinite loop. But the same code works fine after restart. This issue is throwing if I create multiple containers for same project in kie server, even though with different versioning.